# Example $E[X|Y] = E[X]$ for $X, Y$ dependent

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

So I need a counter  example to show that $E[X|Y] = E[X]$ does not necessarily imply independence. My thought:

If $X~\sim\mathcal U(-1,1)$ and $Y=-X$, then $E[X|Y] = \int_\Omega X(\omega)P^{X|Y}(d\omega)$, but $P^{X|Y}:= \frac{P(X\cap Y)}{P(Y)}$ and, as $X$ and $Y$ never coexist, $P(X\cap Y)=0$, giving the desired result $E[X|Y] = E[X]=0$.

Is this correct? I saw an example elsewhere (after I formulated this one) that uses $Y=X^2$. But if both these work, wouldn't this then be true for any $Y=f(X)$ that is disjoint from $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example does not work. $E[X|-X]$ is $X$ itself since $X$ is already meaurable w.r.t. $\sigma (-X)\equiv \sigma (X)$.

Comment: Per the other example, is $X^2$ then not $\sigma (X)$ measurable?

Comment: @OldDogNewTrick No $X$ is measuarble w.r.t. $\sigma (X^{2})$ in general. Intuitively, $X$ is not a function of $X^{2}$ though $X^{2}$ is a function of $X$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following contingency table

[image]

As you can verify

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=0$$

and so is

$$\mathbb{E}[X|Y]=0$$

being

$$\mathbb{E}[X|Y=0]=0\times1$$

$$\mathbb{E}[X|Y=1]=-1\times 0.5+1\times0.5$$

But clearly $X,Y$ are not independent (there are null cells in the contingency table)

In this situation, $X,Y$ are *Regressive independent* because the regression function $E(X|Y)$ is constant (and obviously equal to $E(X)$). This, as shown in the counterexample, does not imply that $X\perp\!\!\!\perp Y$

Answer (score 2):

Take $Y$ to be some positive random variable, $U$ a uniform random variable on $[0,1]$ and $Z$ a Rademacher random variable with parameter $\frac{1}{2}$. Assume that those three random variables are independent. It is known and easy to show that $$-\frac{\log(1-U)}{\lambda}$$ for some positive real number $\lambda$ is an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda$.

Now, set $$X=Z\frac{\log(1-U)}{Y}$$. Thus,
$$\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid Y\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[Z\frac{\log(1-U)}{Y}\mid Y\right]=\frac{1}{Y}\mathbb{E}\left[Z\log(1-U)\mid Y\right].$$
But as $Z$ and $U$ are independent of $Y$, we have
$$\mathbb{E}\left[Z\log(1-U)\mid Y\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[Z\log(1-U)\right]=0.$$ In addition, $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}\left\{\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid Y\right]\right\}=0$.

Of course $X$ and $Y$ are obviously dependent.

My construction might seem a bit elaborate but I wanted it explicit. However, the idea is very simple. Consider a random variable $X$ whose distribution depends of some parameters, say $a$ and $b$. And assume that the expectation of $X$ does not depends on $a$. So, if the parameter $a$ is in fact random, so the conditional expectation of $X$ knowing $a$ does not depend on $a$.

In the exemple above, I choose $X$ to be a Laplace distribution (conditionnaly on $Y$) with random variance (which depends of $Y$) but the expectation of such distitribution does not depend on the variance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your example works... Since if you know the value of $Y$ it is clear which value $X$ will have.

On the other hand, the squared example works because there are two different possible values, one opposed to the other, with the same probability.

**Edit**

In either case, be careful because these random vectors $(X,Y)$ are not "continuous" (the are no the usual integral of a function)

You can contruct an example simpler than the one presented by @hamms.

Consider $Y\sim U([0,1])$ a uniform variable. Then you can consider
$X|Y=y_0 \sim U([-y_0,y_0])$. Obviously $E[X|Y] = 0$ (as a function of $y_0$).

The joint ditribution is null everywhere except in the triangle bounded by the lines $y = 0$, $x = y$ and $x=-y$, where it is
f_{XY}(x,y) = \frac1{2y}. So just compute the marginal density integrating accordingly
$$
f_X(x) = \int f_{XY}(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y = \int_{|x|}^1 \frac1{2y}\,\mathrm{d}y = -\frac12 \ln |x|
$$
Now compute the expectation for $X$. By symmetry it is $0$. Be can be more precise (and boring!):
$$
\begin{align*}
E[X] &= \int_{-1}^1 x f_X(x) \,\mathrm{d}x =
\int_0^1 x f_X(x) \,\mathrm{d}x + \int_{-1}^0 x f_X(x) \,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_0^1 x f_X(x) \,\mathrm{d}x - \int_{-1}^0 |x| f_X(x) \,\mathrm{d}x =
\int_0^1 x f_X(x) \,\mathrm{d}x - \int_0^1 x f_X(x) \,\mathrm{d}x \\
&=0,
\end{align*}
$$
since $f_X(x) = f_X(-x)$.

for $x\in[-1,1]$.